# how to fix this error while installing radium packages in vs code terminal?? thanks

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation

PS C:\Users\BM KHAN\react-guide> npm install --save radium
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-guide@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from radium@0.26.1
npm ERR! node_modules/radium
npm ERR!   radium@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\BM KHAN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\BM KHAN\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-26T07_23_09_921Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\BM KHAN\react-guide>

Comment: @Raja jaganthan help me

Comment: Welcome SO!, try to clear the cache with this command "npm cache clean --force" then do npm install

Comment: sir still encounter the same error

Comment: Please read the error carefully. It is telling you what you can do to fix the error.

Answer (score 12):

It worked for me , I was having the same problem

> npm install --save radium --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me I also have the same problem. If we read the errors currently we can resolve them easily

[image]

```
npm install --save radium --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: can you post the errors as text please? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save radium --force
```